# How to receive emails in two different servers at the same time?

Tags: email, mx-record

My company has been running Yahoo's Bizmail for long time. The usual complaint is that Bizmail does not always sends/receives emails in a timely manner (some emails may appear after 24 hours, but others just go AWOL into the digital mist never to be seen again).

I've already installed our own email server, which presumably works better than Yahoo's, but what I would like to do is to somehow have every email sent to our corporate Bizmail accounts to be received also by my email server. That way, my users would still receive (or not) emails via Yahoo, and the local email server would have a copy of what Yahoo sent to the users, plus a few other emails that presumably went missing there.

I can change the priority of the MX records, but that doesn't provide a copy of the emails.

And why trying to clone my bizmail accounts you may ask? Well, because -sometimes- when you sends us an email using the company address, and copy it to our personal accounts residing on other servers, we get the copy, but never the original. Just like if Yahoo was kind of a black hole that, under the right conditions, swallows incoming and outgoing emails.

Comment: I don't think this is really a programming question; it should probably go to ServerFault or another SE site.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any way to get the sender to send the message simultaneously to two servers.  But you could set the MX records to deliver all mail to your server, and then arrange for your server to automatically forward copies to Bizmail.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge.